# Generic type casting from ReturnType

Tags: c#, generics

I am working with an interceptor (extended from `RealProxy`) which interacts with our caching service. I supply the key and am returned a JSON payload. The return type is reflected from the calling function (`MethodInfo.ReturnType`) and is used to cast the returned `object` as needed.

```
public object Get(string key, Type type) {
    string value = cache[key];
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, type);
}
```

Out of curiosity I wanted to make use of generics to accomplish this. I know you cannot specify a generic type from a Type variable. Is there any way to accomplish the following?

```
public T Get<T>(string key) {
    string value = cache[key];
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
}
```

The calling code is (simplified):

```
Type returnType = methodInfo.ReturnType;
object cachedValue = cacheService.Get(key, returnType);

if (cachedValue != null) {
    // return cached value
} else {
    // continue running
}
```

The reason I am interested in doing this is I would like to use a different caching provider (redis, in particular `StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft`) and our current method of caching/retrieving won't plug in quite so simply with calls like this:

```
User cachedUser = cacheClient.Get<User>("my cache key");
```

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you want to achieve. What do you mean by "accomplish the following" (followed by code that should work fine as far as I can tell)?

Comment: I believe [use reflection to call a generic method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) is what you are looking for (also I'm not really sure how it helps in getting to `User cachedUser = cacheClient.Get<User>("my cache key");`)

Comment: @Blorgbeard that will work, but I only have T is a Type variable gained from reflecting the calling method. You can't do `Type myType = typeof(User); User u = cacheService.Get<myType>();`. I don't want to have to re-write all our caching code to fit a new library, but I feel I might have to do so.

Comment: You meant to notify @AlexeiLevenkov, I think.

Comment: But re your code, if you can do `User u = ` then you can do `cacheService.Get<User>()` - if you know the type at compile-time, you do not have to get it via reflection.

Comment: @hsimah I still have no idea what exactly you are looking for... As @Blorgbeard said if you don't have type at compile time you can't write `User u = ...`, if you have type at compile time - generic code in the post  should work perfectly fine as-is. Some concrete code demonstrating the problem may help, also I suspect you still figuring out what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't made myself clear here @Blorgbeard and @AlexeiLevenkov. The `User` bit is a sample from the redis library I want to use, it is not in my code - I do not know the required type at compile time. Most cache implementations use a cache service injected into code where required. My code base uses interception, so I can't define the type (as in `Get<User>()`) I can only ascertain it via reflection on the intercepted method. I have used the answer in Alexi's first comment and it is working fine with my Get<T>() as defined above.